# ftp server beginner issues

Tags: c, ubuntu, testing, ftp

So, here's the deal.  I am looking at implementing a simple FTP server in c.  Part of that is figuring out a working example.  So, I found the following code online:
http://armi.in/wiki/FTP_Server_and_Client_Implementation_in_C/C++
My question is this: how do I set up these files on my machine (Ubuntu 14.04), so that they run as intended?  Or, do I set them up on different machines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Download the files to your local computer. Make sure you get the "raw" source code text, i.e. not an HTML version. There should be no line numbers. Name the two files `ftpserver.c` and `ftpclient.c`, respectively.
2. Make sure you have a C toolchain installed (`sudo apt-get install gcc` should give you one, if not).
3. Build each program using something like `gcc -o ftpserver ftpserver.c` and `gcc -o ftpclient ftpclient.c`.
4. Run the server by typing `./ftpserver 5000` in the directory where you compiled it. The argument `5000` is the port number to use.
5. Run the client the same way, passing it the same port number argument.

Note: this code is *very probably* not very secure. Do *not*  run it on any Internet-facing machine that doesn't have proper firewalling. You might get hacked.